# cmake incremental build with vs 2015 and llvm-vs2014 toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, llvm

When i use VS 2015 with llvm-vs2014 toolset on my project (project  generated by cmake 3.9) the incremental build is not available: if i restart build or modify only one cpp file, the whole solution is built and it takes time...

In this case, incremental build is not available in VS2015 ? How can i activate it.
An example of my toolchain commands:

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015" -T"LLVM-vs2014" myBuild
msbuild myBuild.sln /t:myPrpoject /maxcpucpunt
```

I tried to modify msbuild parameters but nothing happen

Comment: Have you ever check the `ProjectGuid` after generated by cmake? It seems each time generate the projects, the GUID of the  `ProjectGuid`  changes, which causes incremental build is not available in VS2015.

Comment: I checked the ProjectGuid after cmake re generation and it is the same